# Matplotlib stacked histogram problem with alpha

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot two overlapping histograms in one plot that share the same bar width. As you see in the code the red and blue histogram both use 100 data points but in the plot it looks like there is way more data in the red data set, due to different width of bars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

mu_x = 200
sigma_x = 2
x = np.random.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, size=100)

mu_x = 150
sigma_x = 25
y = np.random.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, size=100)

plt.hist(x, stacked=False, alpha=0.5, bins=10)
plt.hist(y, stacked=False, color="red", alpha=0.5, bins=10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

At first, I thought that stacked=True is what I need but I did not realise what stacked really does.

Now, I see that my question is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43900135/1356000

Comment: A bit confused. What is the expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69657280/how-to-fix-transparency-overlaps-in-matplotlib-when-plotting-multiple-figures

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code is working just as it should be. Of course the colors are getting lighter when you increase the transparency, because transparent colors infront of a white background will look lighter.

What you probably want is that in the overlapping area of the orange and blue bars, the color should be a mix of those. However, your are making an error in this reasoning since this is a stacked plot. There are no overlapping areas. The value of the orange bars is placed ON TOP of the blue bars. Look at it by setting `stacked=False`.

If you want those overlapping areas, then don't plot it stacked but actually plot it over each other like this:

```
plt.hist([x], stacked=False, bins=10, alpha=0.5)
plt.hist([y], stacked=False, bins=10, alpha=0.5)
```

This gives you this plot:
[image]

Comment: Hi sunnytown, thanks for the suggestion. Just updated my question